# Creating numbered directories & grouping them by range

Tags: python

What would be the normal way to do the following? I have some files in a directory (for example):

```
01, 02, 03
10, 15
35
41, 44, 49
```

and I'd like to create and put them in directories like this:

```
01-10
11-20
31-40
41-50
```

I'm not at all sure whether to have a list of ranges, or a list of start/end numbers, or a dictionary. Thanks for any help.

edit: I'm causing some confusion for which I apologize.

I have the following files:

```
01.txt
02.txt
03.txt
10.txt
15.txt
35.txt
41.txt
44.txt
49.txt
```

I have the following directories in the same directory as the above files:

```
01-10
11-20
31-40
41-50
```

I would like to move the .txt files into the directory they belong in.

Comment: Do you want to know how to create a series of numbers, or how to find out what the range should be given some files in a directory? It is not clear what you want.

Comment: Sorry, I'm fine with creating the numbers, I just can't figure out how to create a range based on whether a number falls within start and end point.

Answer (score 3):

Your code should:

1. iterate over each file
2. determine the name of the directory which should contain that file
3. create the directory if it does not exists
4. move the file into the directory

To achieve 2 you should write a function that given the filename returns the corresponding directory name. First you assume that basename of filename is a number:

```
n = int(os.splitext(filename)[0])
```

then use the following expression

```
d = (n-1)//10
```

which gives the correct grouping of numbers  41 -> 4, 50 -> 4. And this one:

```
dir = '%2.2d-%2.2d' % (10*d+1,10*(d+1))
```

which converts 4 -> '41-40'

Comment: I have *no* idea what you are telling me here.

Comment: The first sentence sounds clear? Do you think it is useful to define such function?

Comment: Sorry manu-fatto, none of that helps me at all. Never mind.

Comment: maybe now it is clearer?

Answer (score 1):

Following on from manu-fatto at least this demonstrates the conversion from `filename` to `destdir` name.

Moving a file in a different matter `shutil.move(src, dst)` may help although I think you have to be careful.

```
import os.path

def destdir(filename):
    f =  int(os.path.splitext(filename)[0])
    d = (f - 1) // 10
    return "%02d-%02d" % (10*d+1,10*(d+1))


def filenames():
    """OP to write implementation"""
    n = 23
    for x in range(1, n + 1):
        yield "%02d.txt" % x

for filename in filenames():
    print filename, destdir(filename)
```

Output:

```
01.txt 01-10
02.txt 01-10
03.txt 01-10
04.txt 01-10
05.txt 01-10
06.txt 01-10
07.txt 01-10
08.txt 01-10
09.txt 01-10
10.txt 01-10
11.txt 11-20
12.txt 11-20
13.txt 11-20
14.txt 11-20
15.txt 11-20
16.txt 11-20
17.txt 11-20
18.txt 11-20
19.txt 11-20
20.txt 11-20
21.txt 21-30
22.txt 21-30
23.txt 21-30
```